# How to set default file permissions based on file type?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-permissions

I'm aware that you can set the umask to change the default permissions for any new file created. But i want more granular control than that. What is the least hack-y way to set the default permissions based on a condition, specifically the file type?

In a perfect world umask would have an option that could be used like:

`umask --name *.php 277`

but it doesn't appear that it allows for anything like this.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot set them by filetype (in fact in linux, filetypes have essentially no meaning to the OS at all), but you can set it by process user. If you have a specific user that is processing the .php files, you can set that uses UMASK to the appropriate value. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36220/how-to-set-umask-for-a-system-user

Comment: I'm getting the impression that this is an X-Y issue, so perhaps telling us what the actuall problem is, or what you are trying to accompliish, would help us suggest to you alternative ideas to accomplish it, since UMASK is not quite what you require.

Comment: I am trying to have it so whenever a new file is created its permissions are set to a certain octal, depending on what kind of file it it. That really is what i require. The reason for this is security related. My configuration requires that files of different types have different permissions, i'd prefer if they didn't have to be set manually every time.

Comment: there is no built-in solution to this. you will have to write your own scripts, and look for event hooks you can link your scripts to. If you can't get hooks, perhaps a cron job that executes on a small interval will work.